# Make an RSS feed for all new questions

Tags: feature-request, feed

I want to follow a new Area 51 beta to make sure it goes well, but I can't find an RSS feed for new questions. There is one for specific tags, but not for all questions.

Please provide such a feed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a feed for recent questions. Just use the site's URL in your RSS reader. For example, if I wanted to follow the question feed on [Software QA](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/), I'd plug `https://sqa.stackexchange.com/` as the feed URL.

It's also linked at the bottom of the front page, below all the questions, as "[recent questions feed](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/feeds)".

Comment: That feed does not show all questions. I suspect that it only shows popular or active ones.

Comment: @Tim It shows the 30 most recent questions. Depending on your reader, I think you'd see a history longer than that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I checked again, and it probably shows all questions, but it seems to show the most recently updated questions -- not the most recently published ones.  (Edit: That is, the front-page questions.)